# How to solve Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, local, carrierwave, minimagick

In production my code is working ok, but locally my code was rollbacking when I tried uploading

So I tried forcing the update to accept the uploading with update! which gave me this error message:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in EmployeesController#photo_upload

Validation failed: Photo Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed

So based on that I figured out it had something to do with MiniMagick, with some testing in my uploader file I found that if I commented this line:

```
process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]
```

the problem goes away. The thing is I needed that line for a rectangular image to be loaded as a square image so there's no need to play with every picture and CSS. So I'm looking for a long term solution

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def store_dir
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w[jpg jpeg gif png]
  end

end
```

**Edit:**

Based en a couple of comments mentioning to install ImageMagick locally, I researched because my deployment is in Heroku so it's a little different, but it turns out Heroku has ImageMagick installed so that's clearly not the problem. To those who want to corroborate please type:

```
heroku run identify -version
```

Comment: Did you install either ImageMagick or GraphicMagick with minimagick?

Comment: If you take a look at the [mini magick gem docs](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) in the first line they explain: MiniMagick "A ruby wrapper for ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick command line." So MiniMagick is in fact ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick

Comment: But does minmagick install ImageMagick automatically? If not, then you must install it first. Just because it says it is a wrapper, does not mean it installs ImageMagick or Graphicsmagick. In the same document you reference it says under Requirements: `ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick command-line tool has to be installed.`

Comment: Sure, I've been looking at that, how to install the image_magick_cli inside the gem (every explanation is for a non gem approach and doesn't take CarrierWave into account ). Haven't figured out how or if that is even the right thing to do, still reading documentation

Comment: I'm also looking at [active storage docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) which look fine but the app already has many images loaded via CarrierWave::MiniMagick so it could take some time to implement the change, that without taking into account that some previously uploaded files could be lost in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this problem for like 48hrs now. I figured you just need to do exactly what it says, install ImageMagick. I did `brew install imagemagick` assuming you're on a Mac. My issue was that I was trying to seed image data(as URLs from a `app/assets/images/ folder locally` and that's when the error was popping up. Hope it helps.